# Cropper with canvas drawImage

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, drawimage

Im getting trouble with this cropper.
It seems thats isnt well calibrated but i dont see why.
If the image isnt very large its awfull. Basically i took the image position and add the margin of 120px. then i reduce by m (the slider multiplier) the margin in function of the size of the pic and reduce the crop area to finally enlarge to 320 px.But when it try to crop it took only the top left corner.
If someone could have a look and give me feedback it ll be very nice ^^!!

Here's the main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/step2.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/cropper.css"/>
        <title>Etape 2 sur 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navBar">
            <h4>Étape 2 sur 3</h4>
        </div>
        <div id='avatarBox' class="center-block">

            <h4 class="text-center">Vous pouvez choisir votre photo de profile</h4>
            <div id="imgAvatar" height="320px" widht="320px" class="img-responsive center-block">
                <img id="imgPP" src="./ressources/userProfile.svg" alt="avatar" class="img-thumbnail">           
                <button id="avatarBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true">  Ajouter une photo</span></button>
                <input id="avatarInput" type="file" />
                <button id="nextBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Suivant <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></button>
            </div>        
        </div>

         <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div  class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Positionnez et redimmensionnez</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" role="document">

                        <div class="center-block" id="crop"></div>
                        <div id="dragImg" class="center-block">
                            <img id="imgCrop" height="320"  src="" alt="PictureToCrop">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <span style="left:-490px;font-size: 20pt" class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span><span style="left:-50px;font-size: 20pt" class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span> <div class="center" id="slider"></div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                        <button id="btnCrop" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

         <canvas width="320" height="320"  id="canvasCrop">
                             Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
                        </canvas>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('#avatarBtn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                // Use the native click() of the file input.
                document.querySelector('#avatarInput').click();
            }, false);
        </script>




        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script src="./scripts/filePreview.js">

        </script>

        <script src="./scripts/crop.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts/Step2Observer.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
#navBar{
    background-color: #7CC0FC;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}
#navBar h4{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 20pt;  
}
#avatarBox{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #BEBEC5;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 300px;
}
#imgAvatar{
  height: 180px;
   width: 180px;
}
#avatarInput{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 120%;
    top: -24px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 15pt;
    //custumisation
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#avatarBtn{
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#nextBtn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 102%;
}
```

And the JS

```
               var cropToBase64 = function(){
                //Croppper vars
                var posLeft = $("#dragImg").position().left;
                var posTop = $("#dragImg").position().top;
                var m = $("#slider").slider( "option", "value" );

                //Croppping
                var cropX  = (posLeft<0) ? (Math.abs(posLeft) + 120)/m  : (120 - posLeft)/m;
                var cropY = (posTop<0) ?  (Math.abs(posTop) + 15)/m : (15 - posTop)/m ;
                var c = document.getElementById("canvasCrop");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                var img = document.getElementById("imgCrop");

                ctx.drawImage(img,cropX,cropY,320/m,320/m,0,0,320,320);

               // return c.toDataURL();     
   };
```

Comment: Is there a sample page you could show or can you put this in to JSFiddle or somewhere we can see it?